# нужно посчитать сколько нулей ("0") находится в начале строки. Python. Объясните, как это сделать?

Tags: python

Вам дана строка состоящая только из цифр. Вам нужно посчитать сколько нулей ("0") находится в начале строки.

Пример:

```
('001') = 2
('100100') = 0
('001001') = 2
('012345679') = 1
('0000') = 4
```

Строка может иметь цифры: 0-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
string = str(input())
check = 0

for i in string:
    if i == '0':
        check += 1
    else:
        break
print(check)
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с "однострочником":

```py
s = "0002344"
print(next(i for i, x in enumerate(s) if x != '0'))
# 3
```